Android chrome после скрытия клавиатуры, на короткое время остается пустой блок
происходит это когда находишься в конце страницы, выбираешь input, происходит позиционировае к этому input и после закрытия клавиатуры есть задержка пока виден пустой блок, потом происходит смещение и пустого блока не остается


это общая проблема хрома на андроид или есть варианты исправить? в ios хром, такого блока нет
